# Sorting a collection according to the child with shortest string length

Tags: laravel, sorting

I'm using laravel 5.7.

I have a parent class "users" which can have many children "comments".
I'm trying to sort a collection according to string lengths of the comments, in a way that a user appears early in the collection if he has any short strings, regardless how long his other strings are.

Currently I have this code, which works fine when the users only have one comment. But when they have multiple strings, it chooses the longest string available for each user (or maybe it's calculating the total string length? for the user) to sort by, instead of the shortest one

```
$collection = User::with('comments')->get();
$comment_length = 'comments.questions';
$collection = $collection->sortBy(function($comment_length) { return strlen($comment_length );});
```

so if I have for example

```
user1->comment1 = "srt"
user1->comment2 = "superduperveryverylong"

user2->comment1 = "short"

user3->comment1 = "longer1"
user3->comment2 = "longer2"
user3->comment3 = "longer3"
```

I want the order to be [1,2,3] but get [2,3,1].
The number of comments is irrelevant (when >0)

Any ideas how to write a sorting function for this situation?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with php's [usort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) function.

```
// Used to determine the max length of a users comments
$maxCommentLength = function ($max, $comment) {
   $length = strlen($comment->???);
   if ($length > $max) {
       return $length;
   }
     
   return $max;
};

// Sort the users array using a comparator function and our max length helper
$sorted = usort($users, function ($u1, $u2) use ($maxCommentLength) {
    $max1 = $u1->comments->reduce($maxCommentLength, 0);
    $max2 = $u2->comments->reduce($maxCommentLength, 0);
    
    // Shift element right
    if ($max1 > $max2) {
        return 1;
    }
    
    // Shift element left
    if ($max1 < $max2) {
        return -1;
    }
    
    // Keep same index
    return 0;
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I needed to modify the algorithm a bit to find the shortest comment (and not the max one), and use $collection->sort() instead of usort because it's an object and not an array, but that did the trick. :)

Comment: Good job! Glad to help.